# How to setup Phoenix PubSub subscriber callbacks

Tags: redis, elixir, publish-subscribe, phoenix-framework

I've got a fairly straightforward requirement centered around 2 services (for now) built in Phoenix:

`ServiceA` is responsible for registering users. When a user is registered, `ServiceA` broadcasts a message with info about the newly created user. This is being done using the following code in a Controller action right now:

`ServiceA.Endpoint.broadcast("activity:all", "new:user", %{email: "test@test.com"})`

`ServiceB` is responsible for listening out for all of these activity broadcasts and doing something with them (essentially building up a feed of activity).

I've hit a stumbling block in that I can see `ServiceA` broadcasting the message to Redis (using `Phoenix.PubSub.Redis`), but don't fully understand how to get the subscriber on `ServiceB` to process it...

The following piece of code is as far as I've managed to get, which does *something* when a message is broadcast and then raises an exception.

**Partial Subscriber Module**

```
defmodule ServiceB.UserSubscriber do

  def start_link do
    sub = spawn_link &(process_feed/0)
    ServiceB.Endpoint.subscribe(:user_pubsub, "activity:all")
    {:ok, sub}
  end

  def process_feed do
    receive do
      params ->
        IO.inspect "processing goes here..."
    end
    process_feed
  end

end
```

**Exception**

```
[error] GenServer :user_pubsub terminating
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.PubSub.RedisServer.handle_info/2
```

I'm guessing I've missed a whole load of `GenServer` work somewhere, but can't seem to find anything online that suggests *where*.

Answer (score 9):

The problem (as expected) was that my Subscriber module wasn't implemented as a GenServer but I was trying to replicate the same functionality (and badly!). Updating my Subscriber Model as follows has done the trick:

```
defmodule SubscriberService.ActivitySubscriber do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(channel) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, channel)
  end

  def init(channel) do
    pid = self
    ref = SubscriberService.Endpoint.subscribe(pid, channel)
    {:ok, {pid, channel, ref}}
  end

  def handle_info(%{event: "new:user"} = message, state) do
    IO.inspect "#######################"
    IO.inspect "New User - Received Message:"
    IO.inspect message
    IO.inspect "#######################"
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_info(message, state) do
    IO.inspect "#######################"
    IO.inspect "Catch All - Received Message:"
    IO.inspect message
    IO.inspect "#######################"
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

As you can see, `init/1` triggers the subscription, and the `handle_info/2` functions receive the incoming messages.

If you want to see how it works in all its glory (both Publisher and Subscriber services), [take a look at the repo](https://github.com/mattweldon/phoenix_pub_sub_sandbox).